# Count only successful move attempts

Tags: bash

Problem is that I cannot figured out how to count only "successful" attempts of move files.

My script take directories from $PATH as destination and tries to take files from specified directory (until the directory is empty) , shuffle them in random order and move to directories from $PATH.

```
x=0
while [[ $(ls -A Directory/jpg | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
do
  for i in "${destination[@]}"
  do
    shuf -zn1 -e Directory/jpg/*.jpg | xargs -0 mv -vt $i/somedir 2>/dev/null
    x=$((x + 1))
  done
done
```

My "x" counter is actually greater then number of files that were in "Directory/jpg" and I would like to "x" represent only exact numbers of files that were copied.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the script a bit for testing:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                             
destination[0]=dest1
destination[1]=dest2
destination[2]=dest3
x=0
while [[ $(ls -A source | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
do
  for i in "${destination[@]}"
  do
    shuf -zn1 -e source/* | xargs -0 mv -vt $i
    x=$((x + 1))
  done
done

echo $x
```

So with three destination directories and different numbers of files in `source`, I noticed that `x` was always a multiple of the number of elements of the `destination` array.

Removing the `2>/dev/null` revealed a hidden problem:

```
... # other mv output
renamed 'source/file14' -> 'dest2/file14'
renamed 'source/file16' -> 'dest3/file16'
renamed 'source/file5' -> 'dest1/file5'
mv: cannot stat 'source/*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'source/*': No such file or directory
```

The last two failed moves were counted!

`for i in "${destination[@]}"` is always going to loop a number of times equal to the number of elements in the `destination` array.  That is, if `destination` has three elements, the loop will always execute with `i = 1`, `i = 2`, and `i = 3`, even if there are not that many files.  The for loop will always increase `x` by the number of elements in `destination`.  So, `x` will be greater than the number of files moved. (unless the number of files is a multiple of the number of elements in the destination array)

This can be fixed by adding a test to the inside of the for loop to check that more files to move exist:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                             
destination[0]=dest1
destination[1]=dest2
destination[2]=dest3
x=0
while [[ $(ls -A source | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
do
  for i in "${destination[@]}"
  do
    shuf -zn1 -e source/* | xargs -0 mv -vt $i
    x=$((x + 1))
    [[ $(ls -A source | wc -l) -eq 0 ]] && break # exit the loop if there are no more files to move
  done
done
```

Comment: Great. It works perfectly. 
I was aware that in my code errors were responsible for incrase "x", but didn't know how to test success condition.
Again, valuable lesson for me !

Comment: What `-a source/*` actually does is testing whether there is a file named `*` in the `source` directory, which is most likely `false`. Combined with `!`, it makes it a `true` statement and your `for` loop will always break after first iteration, effectively moving all files to the first destination folder.

Comment: Correct, I assumed the shell would expand the `*` and didn't look closely enough at the `mv` output in testing.  A valid test for breaking is `$(ls -A source | wc -l) -eq 0`.  I've deleted my previous comment and updated the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using && to check the result of the mv command and execute the increment conditionally.

Here's the bash idiom:

```
command && other-command-if-command-was successful
```

In the example above, other-command will be executed only if command returned a zero exit status.  Here's my edit to your program:

```
x=0
while [[ $(ls -A Directory/jpg | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
do
  for i in "${destination[@]}"
  do
    shuf -zn1 -e Directory/jpg/*.jpg | xargs -0 mv -vt $i/somedir 2>/dev/null && x=$((x + 1))
  done
done
```

The code above probably incorrectly assumes that xargs will return the exit status of mv.  I think that it won't.  Rather, it's probably best to avoid xargs in this case altogether.  After all,  shuf is only returning a single entry.  Here's a larger modification of the code that will work better:

```
x=0
while [[ $(ls -A Directory/jpg | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
do
  for i in "${destination[@]}"
  do
    random_file=$(shuf -zn1 -e Directory/jpg/*.jpg) 
    mv "$random_file" "$i/somedir" && x=$((x + 1))
  done
done
```

Comment: That being said, it is likely that the exit status reported will be that of xargs.  I need to verify that xargs will propagage the mv status.  It's unlikely that it will.  I think I'm going to suggest we avoid the use of xargs completely.  I'll add new code and leave this comment so it might be helpful to the discussion.